# Adding custom UITableViewCell crashes the simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

Im trying to build my application using a custom `UITableViewCell`. This is the code in my `UIViewController` that adds the `viewCell` to the table:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    NSLog(@"------- Tableview --------");

    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cellView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tblCellView" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellView objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell setLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"indexpath.row: %d", indexPath.row]];


    //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"bös";
    return cell;
    }
```

If I uncomment the line above "return cell" it returns a regular `UITableViewCell` without any errors, but as soon as i try to implement my custom cell it crashes with this error:

> ------- Tableview -------- 2010-04-23 11:17:33.163 Golf[26935:40b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-984.38/UITableView.m:4709 2010-04-23
>   11:17:33.164 Golf[26935:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView
>   dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
>   2010-04-23 11:17:33.165 Golf[26935:40b] Stack: (
>
> ...

I have configured the .xib file as one should with the proper outlets. And the identifier of the UITableViewCell corresponds with name im trying to load from NSBundle

Comment: Try casting it to (MyTableCell *)

Comment: don't forget to import custom cell in .m file and binding with custom cell.and also check tableview delegates for datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also make sure to set the Custom Class type in Interface Builder to the corresponding class name ( which is `MyTableCell` in your example ), otherwise casting won't work either.

Comment: This is an old question, but i believe this was the solution to my problem so I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this answer led me to find it. I had forgotten to set the type of File's Owner to be my view controller in my iPhone xib so I was crashing only on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see where `tblCell` is declared and that could be one of many issues with your code. First of all you need to do something like:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (MyTableCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

You are just loading the nib but never extracting the cell from it.

--Update--

You should also check your custom cell in IB if it has any errors or incorrect bindings.

Comment: Im sorry, that was old code. I have now updated my original question.

Comment: Try casting it to (MyTableCell *)

Answer (score 1):

I created this define to help

```
#define LoadViewNib(__NIBNAME__) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:__NIBNAME__ owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
```

for use, you can only do this

```
 if(cell == nil) {

        cell = LoadViewNib(@"MyCellNibName");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `loadNibNamed:` nethod returns nil for some reason. So resulting cell object nil too.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7)

If you are loading your own custom cell then, *"An important attribute to set for the programmatic portion of this procedure is each object’s tag property. Find this property in the View section of the Attributes pane and assign each object a unique integer."*

**Now retrieve your label like this**
(I suppose you assign tag=1 to label)

```
UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
cellLabel.text = @"Your text goes here"
```